# Trying to use setTimeout to create a small delay, but it's not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, settimeout

I have some jQuery/JavaScript like this:

```
$("#dialog-coin-flip").dialog({
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    closeText: "Close",
    buttons: {
        "Flip": function() {
            $(this).children("div").html("Flipping...");
            var flipResult = coinFlip();
            setTimeout($(this).children("div").html(flipResult), 1000);
        },
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
    }
});

function coinFlip() {
    var flipResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    if (flipResult === 0) {
        return "You flipped a coin and it came up heads.";
    }
    else if (flipResult === 1) {
        return "You flipped a coin and it came up tails.";
    } 
}
```

When I click the button "Flip" I get the message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

In Chrome's JavaScript console after the 1000ms has passed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line do you get the error?

Comment: trying wrapping what you want to do after the time has elapsed in an anoymous function: setTimeout(function() { setTimeout($(this).children("div").html(flipResult), 1000); }, 1000).  SetTimeout wants a function pointer to call after the time has elapsed.

Comment: No line number is mentioned. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include your code inside a function.
try to use this:

```
var $here = $(this);
setTimeout(function() { 
    $here.children("div").html(flipResult); 
}, 1000);
```

instead of this:

```
setTimeout($(this).children("div").html(flipResult), 1000);
```

Comment: Yay!  Worked perfectly.  Sometimes JS can be so pesky. :)